How to open a file, with a specific program in C++
So in windows, you can right click a file, and open it with a specified program. If it matters, the specific program I want to target is Clip Studio Paint, but this generally works with most programs from the Windows 11 UI.
This also works with ClipStudioPaint, I can right click on an image, choose the clip studio paint program, and it opens.
How can I do this from C++? I.e. I want to get a list of image files, and then "open/spawn" the target process, as if the user had clicked through the normal UI.
I'd also accept figuring out how to do this as a shell exec ... like is there some magic batch programming code that would do the same thing?
Is there some MSDN or WinApi call? Or is there some kind of executing procedure?

@KenWhite That kind of works, i.e. I can shellexecute cmd.exe /C clipstudiopaint.exe absolute\path\to.png and it opens... I was wondering if there's a wine32api call specifically... Not sure how QDesktopServices::openUrl is implemented... But at least you put me on the right trail for a good option.

No. ShellExecute the image file, leaving the verb empty, and Windows will start the associated app with the default action, which with images should be 'open'. Don't use cmd.exe at all. Don't use any executable at all. If there is an app associated with the .png extension, it will open the file. And if clipstudiopaint.exe is not the default app for .,png files, then just ShellExecute cipstudiopaint.exe and pass it the name of the .png file. In no case do you need to use cmd.exe.

Dont use ShellExecute() to run a specific EXE file, use CreateProcess() instead. But, if you must use ShellExecute and want to run a specific command, you need to know the registered verb for that command, if it has one. Many files have more verbs than just 'open'. But, not all right-click menu commands use verbs. Some use Shell extensions instead, which can be accessed by querying the OS for the file's IContextMenu interface.
